# Adding two SUM DISTINCT values, MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following query to gathering and SUM info about some specific data in my MySQL table:

```
SELECT rowid,
    id_name,
    SUM(DISTINCT colA) AS colAtotal,
    SUM(DISTINCT colB) AS colBtotal
FROM orders
```

I know I can add colAtotal and colBtotal together with PHP after the query, but I need 'total' column to build by sort with in the query.

How can I add '(SUM(DISTINCT colA) as colAtotal, SUM(DISTINCT colB) as colBtotal)' together in the query so I will have another column for my sort?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just add them together? `SUM(DISTINCT colA) + SUM(DISTINCT colB)` -- Also, did you intend to `GROUP BY` any field?

Comment: no, not for grouping - that is what I was using DISTINCT for. Ive tried adding them together, but I cannot nail down the parentheses order.

Comment: In this case, `distinct` is different than `group by`.  But if it is returning your desired results, then just add the 2 columns and you're done.  Sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/faa23/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add them up.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(DISTINCT colA) AS colAtotal,
    SUM(DISTINCT colB) AS colBtotal,
    SUM(DISTINCT colA) + SUM(DISTINCT colB) AS colAplusBtotal
FROM orders
```

You can remove the separate sums if you don't need them

```
SELECT 
    SUM(DISTINCT colA) + SUM(DISTINCT colB) AS colAplusBtotal
FROM orders
```

Or if you want to sort by it:

Just add them up.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(DISTINCT colA) AS colAtotal,
    SUM(DISTINCT colB) AS colBtotal
FROM orders
ORDER BY  
    SUM(DISTINCT colA) + SUM(DISTINCT colB)
```

Note, there is no column alias when you add it in ORDER BY. Since the field is not returned, it wouldn't make sense to give it an alias.

I've removed the other (non-aggregated) fields, since you're not grouping by them. Keeping them might just confuse you, since they are basically random values.

Note though, that `DISTINCT` may not do what you expect. This formula adds up all *different* order amounts, provided that colA and colB are amounts. So if you have one million orders, but they all happen to have values of either 10 or 17 then the result of such a `sum` will be `27`, since only the unique values are added up.

I can't look in your head, of course, but I expect you seek something like this, to get the total amount per customer or something:

```
SELECT 
    Customer,
    SUM(colA) AS colAtotal,
    SUM(colB) AS colBtotal
FROM orders
GROUP BY Customer
ORDER BY 
    SUM(colA) + SUM(colB)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input;Im grouping by ID, but Im going to use the new column with the sum of the two DISTINCT columns in the ORDER BY. Am I understanding you correctly that ORDER BY removes the unique column that would be made by adding the two together? To complicate the issue ORDER BY is being controlled by a PHP switch.

Comment: No, no. You can order by the same expression. So you can select it, like in the first snippen, and order by it, like in the third snippet. There's no reason why you can't have both. It might seem useless to have the sum 6 times (2 separate, 2 added up as a field and 2 added up in order by), but the query optimizer will probably take that into account and calculate the actual sum of each field only once.